"Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" message randomly appears when using selenium
I'm new to Selenium, and I was making a program that scrapes jobs from LinkedIn. However, while running the code, the message "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" would randomly appear in the console and disrupt the work of the program.
I tried using ChatGPT to help but it didn't manage to help me. Any idea how I can disable this message?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

According to https://github.com/google-ai-edge/mediapipe/issues/3017 the message "Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU" is an info message. You can suppress it by simply adding
options.add_argument('--log-level=1')

to your webdriver's options.
